# Limit of an integral in the form of $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x) \int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

while preparing my next exam I found this exercise in the exam of two years ago: 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sinh(x)}{\cos(x)-1}  \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{e^t-t^4} dt$$
I first thought to use de L'Hopital rule, but it didn't feel right so I tried another way. I decided to try to expand the function inside the integral using McLaurin series. So the function became:
 $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sinh(x)}{\cos(x)-1}  \int_{0}^{x} (1+\frac t 2 + \frac {t^2} 4+ \frac {t^3} {12} + \frac {25t^4}{48}+\mathcal{o}(t^4)) dt$$
After expanding $\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cos(x)-1}$ and integrating and some other algebric steps, it came down to $$\frac{x^2} {\frac{-x^2} 2}$$ the result was -2.
My problem is that I'm not sure I could actually do everything I did. I someone could explain to me whether I'm right or not, and maybe also explain to me how to approach this type of exercises I would be extremely thankful. I would like to apologize already for the spelling mistakes I made for sure, but I'm not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sinh(x)\sim x$ and $\cos(x)-1\sim -\frac{x^2}2$ as $x\to 0$ we get
$$\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cos(x)-1}  \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{e^t-t^4}\mathrm dt\sim-\frac2{x}\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{e^t-t^4}\mathrm dt$$
De L'Hopital rule reduces it to
$$-2\sqrt{e^x-x^4}\xrightarrow{x\to 0}-2$$

Answer (score 2):

What you did is right, but your first thought (L'Hospital) would be a quicker way to do this problem. If you let $$f(x)=\int_0^x\sqrt{e^x-x^4}dx,$$ then the limit is 
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sinh (x)f(x)}{\cos (x)-1},$$
and since $f'(x)=\sqrt{e^x-x^4}$, using L'Hospital twice will give you the answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem is easily handled by rewriting the expression under limit as $$-\dfrac{x^2} {\sin^2 x}\cdot\frac{\sinh x} {x} \cdot (\cos x +1)\cdot\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$$ where $f(t) =\sqrt{e^t-t^4}$. Now the limit of first fraction is $1$, that of second fraction is $1$, that of third factor is $2$ and the last factor tends to $f(0)=1$ via Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. The desired answer is thus $-2$.

---

If you see an integral of type $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt $ in limit evaluation as $x\to 0$, it makes sense to rewrite it as $$x\cdot\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$$ and then one uses FTC.

Answer (score 1):

*Just small comments.*

Apparently, you did not develop correctly the integrand since
$$e^t-t^4=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{6}-\frac{23 t^4}{24}+O\left(t^5\right)$$ makes
$$\sqrt{e^t-t^4}=1+\frac{t}{2}+\frac{t^2}{8}+\frac{t^3}{48}-\frac{191 t^4}{384}+O\left(t^5\right)$$
$$\int_0^x\sqrt{e^t-t^4}\,dt=x+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^3}{24}+\frac{x^4}{192}-\frac{191
   x^5}{1920}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
Now, using the standard series for $\sinh(x)$ and $\cos(x)$, we then have 
$$ \frac{\sinh(x)}{\cos(x)-1}  \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{e^t-t^4}\,dt=\frac{\left( x+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O\left(x^7\right)\right)\left(x+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^3}{24}+\frac{x^4}{192}-\frac{191
   x^5}{1920}+O\left(x^6\right) \right)}{ -\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+O\left(x^7\right)}$$ Expand and perform long division to get
$$ \frac{\sinh(x)}{\cos(x)-1}  \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{e^t-t^4}\,dt=-2-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{7 x^2}{12}-\frac{13 x^3}{96}+\frac{361   x^4}{2880}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ which, for sure, shows the limit and how it is approached.

Moreover, this truncated series allows a quick estimation of the integral up to the limit where
$$e^t=t^4 \implies t=-4 W\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right) \approx 1.42961$$

SOme results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & \text{approximation}& \text{exact} \\
 0.1 & -2.05596 & -2.05596 \\
 0.2 & -2.12422 & -2.12424 \\
 0.3 & -2.20514 & -2.20534 \\
 0.4 & -2.29879 & -2.29958 \\
 0.5 & -2.40493 & -2.40716 \\
 0.6 & -2.52301 & -2.52815 \\
 0.7 & -2.65219 & -2.66241 \\
 0.8 & -2.79132 & -2.80947 \\
 0.9 & -2.93898 & -2.96833 \\
 1.0 & -3.09340 & -3.13710 \\
 1.1 & -3.25255 & -3.31242 \\
 1.2 & -3.41408 & -3.48819 \\
 1.3 & -3.57534 & -3.65282 \\
 1.4 & -3.73338 & -3.77878
\end{array}
\right)$$